# Unmanaged DLL loading path

Tags: .net, dll, c++-cli

I have a managed c++/cli project that wraps an unmanaged dll.

I load the unmanaged dll with `LoadLibrary`, but the `LoadLibrary` call can't find my dll.

```
  HMODULE theDllHell = LoadLibrary(L"mylib.dll");
```

What do I have to do, so that my dll gets copied to the output directory and what path do I have to supply to `LoadLibrary`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Assuming that you have the DLL added to the project, and it is visible inside the SolutionExplorer panel, just right-click on it and:

- in BuildAction to "Content"
- in CopyToOutputDir select 'CopyIfNewer'

If I did not misremembered the options, it should be now copied to output dir whenever it is reasonable. Ref: [File Properties on MSDN](http://web.archive.org/web/20121116072531/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx)

Second: The LoadLibrary searches a series of paths in a traditional Windows-specific order. The paths that you can be **almost** always sure are:

- your current workind directory
- the system DLL directories, like %windir%\system32

Please check the docs: [LoadLibraryA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) there's for example 'SetDllDirectory' mentioned which you mind find very useful. Also, here's the search paths order explained in details: [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order)

edit: of course you can just provide to the LoadLibrary the CWD-relative or full-absolute path to the file. That always solves the problem, but - I do not recommend it, as determinig the paths manually may be not a trivial task when the app is to be run on various versions and languages of the OS!

Answer (score 1):

To load library from the current or exe directory it is enough only library name, without path. For full Dll search order, see Dynamic-Link Library Search Order http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
The directory from which the application loaded.
The current directory.
The system directory. Use the GetSystemDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
The 16-bit system directory. There is no function that obtains the path of this directory, but it is searched.
The Windows directory. Use the GetWindowsDirectory function to get the path of this directory.
The directories that are listed in the PATH environment variable.
```

If you want to copy library to the output directory, add this library project to solution. Add modules will be in the same directory. You can also use Post-Build Step in the mylib project to copy mylib.dll to any directory you need.

Comment: The search order is actually [considerably more complicated than that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686203.aspx).  Your link has *most* of the details, just don't want people trusting the list in your answer instead of visiting the link.